# configure hibernate with spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm trying integrate spring with hibernate but catch NamingException: Context is read only

**stacktrace**

```
WARNING: Could not bind factory to JNDI
javax.naming.NamingException: Context is read only
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.checkWritable(NamingContext.java:903)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:517)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:538)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.createSubcontext(SelectorContext.java:422)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.bind(NamingHelper.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

**configs**

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/school"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="toor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hib.cfg.xml"/>
</bean>
```

hib.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="java:hibernate/SessionFactory">
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
        </property>
        <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>
        <property name="configClass">org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</property>

        <mapping class="com.domain.Worker"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

How i can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to run this stand alone or within an application container?

Comment: @Ross I'm running it using tomcat.

Comment: If you were running an EJB container binding the session factory to JNDI will work, in this case you're not so removing it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try deleting the session factory name from your hib.cfg.xml file so that it looks like:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
        </property>
        <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>
        <property name="configClass">org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</property>

        <mapping class="com.domain.Worker"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```